# NullPointerException on FileInput/OutputStream on jar

Tags: java, netbeans, inputstream

I'm working on application that causes me many problems when working

```
file1 = "src\\sga\\facturation\\data.ser";
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputrStream(file1);//this works fine on NetBeans
```

I tried

```
file1 = "data.ser";
InputStream fis = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file1);
```

But nothing; I tried also to change the repertory's path, it told me file not found, I tried even to force the repertory in C:\Folder; where I put my files but nothing works.
I tried to delete those lines to see if FileOutputStream works, but it's not the case :(
Here's which works on NetBeans

```
 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file2));
```

This is my repertory

[My Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWAZw.png)

Thanks for helping 
RELATED POSTS NEVER TOLD ME A SOLUTION WHICH WORK, SO IF YOUR ATTENTION WAS TO PUT A -1 ON BEGINING, DO IT AND LEAVE !

Comment: is your file, that you ar trying to load in your Jar or outside next to the Jar? also do you have the src file next the jar when you compile it?

Comment: My file must be in the same directory than classes (all classes are also in src/sga/facturation)

Comment: does the output jar have a space in its name or something?

Comment: its name is "SGA-Facturation.jar"

Comment: Are you sure that your build system has actually put the file into JAR? Rename it to *.ZIP and inspect with an archive manager.

Comment: Affirmative, all files are in the same folder with classes !

Comment: I tried this, now it gives me same error on declaration of the ObjectInputStream; should I use another thing or .. ?!

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would load a file that's located in your jar with: `InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("my/path/to.file");` but you have to be careful that if the jar or the directory the jar is in has a space it bugs out sometimes. I remember trying this like a year ago. Try the jar and the file thats its located in renaming it.

Their might also be a problem with dir permissions, try running your jar like a administrator

Comment: My path to the file is `"src\\sga\\facturation\\data.ser"` but the jar when unzipin, doesn't contain src ....

Comment: @John Doe in the src you should have your .class files and eventually sga//factuarion/data.ser or something like that :P check if you have your files really in your netbeans src folder

Answer (score 0):

FileInputStream resolves relative path based on current working directory. In your IDE working directory may be different from what it is for standalone program. Use absolute path instead.

Comment: When I try to this, and printing the patrh I got this:
`C:\bla\bla\bla\SGA-Facturation.jar!\sga\facturation\data.ser`
And a syntax error on the path :/

Comment: Well, you  can't read archives using File API. URL.openStream() may work

Comment: How could I use it? will the URL be just the name of file, or all the path? with ou wothout src ?!